# Mysql data from table with condition

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql tables as follows:

contacts

```
---------------
id | name | email
---------------
1  | Jack | jack@test.com
2  | John | john@test.com
3  | Liz  | liz@test.com
5  | Jack | jack@test.com
6  | Liz  | liz@test.com
7  | Mike | mike@test.com
8  | Jack | jack@test.com
```

purchases

```
-------------------
id | contact_id | paid
-------------------
1  | 3          | true
2  | 5          | true
```

I need unique contact_ids that made purchase and other unique contact_ids that don't have made purchases.

So the final result will be as:

```
-------------------
id | name | email
------------------
2  | John | john@test.com
3  | Liz  | liz@test.com
5  | Jack | jack@test.com
7  | Mike | mike@test.com
```

I tried the query as:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts LEFT JOIN purchases ON contacts.id = purchases.user_id
```

But this is not giving me unique rows as required. I tried several combination of DISTINCT, but I am not getting the result as required.

Comment: *unique contact_ids that don't have made purchases.*   and after *final result will be as:* `3  | Liz  | liz@test.com,5  | Jack | jack@test.com` So I don't understand did **3  | Liz** made purchase or not `purchases |1|3|true` ? and what is your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try this?

```
SELECT COALESCE(purchases.contact_id, contacts.id) as id, name, email
FROM contacts 
LEFT JOIN purchases ON contacts.id = purchases.user_id
GROUP BY name
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2262/7)

Comment: Hi John, If you see in the result, the id of Liz and Jack should be from purchase table, that is not I am getting with the solution.

Comment: @Lalu I uploaded a sql fiddle with the correct result. can you verify?

Comment: Works perfectly John! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work, but its performance is "?".

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT id as i FROM purchases
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT contact_id as i FROM purchases
    )
GROUP BY id
```